# Accessing both User Management API and custom API for SPA using Auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I am building an SPA which has to access User Management API directly and also need to authorize a custom API.

The library I use was auth0-js.

According to the document, if I want to access the User Management API, I have to get the accessToken first by reaching the `/authorize` endpoint which provided by auth0.

Also I have to provide a specific string to `audience` parameter for that.

And if I want to authorize additional custom API, I have to reaching the `/authorize` endpoint again by providing a different set of params including `audience` to get a different access token.

Is there any easy way for me to enter `/authorize` endpoint one time and get an access token that can both used for User Management API and my custom API ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You should not be getting an access token for [Management APIv2](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2) via Implicit grant flow used in SPAs. Only authorized non-interactive applications/clients should be used to get a Management APIv2 access token and the request should be initiated from a secure server and not from the browser. This is the recommended approach to receive a secure token for an API. You can read the guide on this [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/get-access-tokens-for-production).

You can get a Management APIv2 token using Client Credentials grant using your own server, or depending on the use-case, request it via Auth0 Rules (which run after user authentication) and call the Management APIv2 endpoints in there in a secured Webtask container. You can read more it [here](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/guides/management-api).